# UPN vs DOMAIN\USER signin

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2012, windows-domain

What is the difference between using user@zone.domain.tld over DOMAIN\USER? Does the difference come in to play the bigger the AD/business network is?

For my setup I have now I can use either/or and it works but from what I have learned there is a difference.

Answer (score 4):

**Short Version:** Use the UserPrincipalName if you can. If you can't, no big deal.

**Long Version:**

DOMAIN\USER login names, the USER portion also known as the sAMAccountName, is really just an old carry-over from the Windows NT days. Microsoft's preference since Windows 2000 Active Directory is for users to use the e-mail-style login name, the userPrincipalName.

The userPrincipalName (the e-mail-style login) is, from what I remember, intended to mirror the user's email address. This lets users remember one unique ID for logging into domain resources, email, etc.

UPNs are also impervious to other domain changes, e.g., renaming or removing a domain. That is, if you move users to another domain and delete their original domain, the UPN remains the same. Users can still login, blissfully unaware of the havoc you have wrought. ;-)

Also, the UPN does not necessarily have to match the name of the domain that the user is in. This is handy, for example, for corporate takeovers. One company can buy another, and the UPNs of the acquired company's users can be updated even before the domains are actually consolidated.